# Postfix Not resolving outlook domain names (length??)

Tags: email, postfix

Hello Server Geniuses.    Im running a full stack email server, dockerized. Having trouble sending email to outlook email addresses. (and only outlook email addresses)    I have a theory.

The error I receive is strictly a DNS resolution error

```
    for name=myradar-com.mail.protection.outlook.com type=A: Host not found,
    try again
```

On the server, If I try to  test resolve the address, using the command

```
 sudo docker-compose exec postfix-mailcow nslookup myradar-com.mail.protection.outlook.com
```

I am presented with a timeout error.  Once in a while, I'll get a SERVEFAIL error.

If run the exact same command with unbound (also running in the same stack)  then it resolves with no problem.

If I try to resolve just the "outlook.com"  portion, it works.

*I have a theory that Postfix just doesn't recognize a sub.sub.sub.domain.tld  as a valid FQDN, and I think its just ignoring the request and not passing it to the resolver at all.   I am trying to find "somewhere" in the master.cf or any other config file that instructs postfix on what the correct format of a domain name is, but I am not having any luck.*  I could also be completely wrong, and maybe something else is wrong (maybe the way postfix is looking for an "A" record for that host???, but then again, unbound works.)

Can anyone help with this issue?  or maybe point me in a place to look for an answer?

Edit. I have proved the subdomain levels are not the issue.

Comment: Try to use tcpdump and figure out if maybe it is a difference in UDP vs TCP requests.

Comment: Ill have to learn to use it, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Can you show the full output from calling `dig` against the unbound instance in a running container, probably like `docker exec -it postfix-mailcow dig myradar-com.mail.protection.outlook.com @172.22.1.254`? (And confirm this really is the resolver IP configured inside the container via `/etc/resolv.conf` and a copy in `/var/spool/postfix/`)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue "only" when sending to emails that use Office 365 / Outlook. To fix it I had to disable DNSSEC.

/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/custom.conf
or /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

#DNSSEC=no

Its off by default when commented.

Looks like Office 365 / Outlook does not support DNSSEC? But Hotmail does.